# Links return to homepage domain name

Tags: html, server

I have a website and every time I insert a link, it redirects to: `www.MyDomain.com/"http://linkurl.com"`

Its something related to htaccess maybe?

Why is this happening? Thank you :)

Comment: show us one of your links you have on your website. The code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you probably have double quotes around your anchor `href` such as:

```
<a href='"http://test.com"'>test</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xy8hm640/

This will evaluate as a relative URL.

Change to:

```
<a href="http://test.com">test</a>
```